# How the bot mention people if someone boost/unboost the server

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

My bot sends the message if someone boosts/unboosts the server.

You can see my code here:

```js
client.on("guildMemberUpdate", (oldMember, newMember) => {
  const oldStatus = oldMember.premiumSince;
  const newStatus = newMember.premiumSince;

  if (!oldStatus && newStatus) {
    client.channels.cache
        .get("channel id")
        .send(`Thank you ${newMember.user.tag} (:`);
  }

  if (oldStatus && !newStatus) {
    client.channels.cache
        .get("channel id")
        .send(`woah ${newMember.user.tag}, unboost this server`);
  }
});
```

The code works perfectly, there is no error, but the bot is not tagging people, just mentioning the tag name like this:

[image]

I want the bot to mention people like this instead:

[image]

I think the problem is `${newMember.user.tag}`. Usually, I use `<@${member.id}>`, but I don't know how to fix this code if using `{user.tag}`.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaro Yes! it works perfectly, sorry bro I forgot to click the upvote button

Comment: No worries, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use:

`` .send(`woah <@${newMember.id}>, unboost this server`) ``

or simply:

`` .send(`woah ${newMember}, unboost this server`) ``